# How to use albatross with miktex on Windows?

Tags: miktex, windows, command-line

I am trying to get [albatross](https://ctan.org/pkg/albatross) to work with miktex on a Windows machine. Trying `albatross --version` at the command line tells me `albatross` is not a recognized command. In my miktex installation, I see `albatross.jar` and `albatross.sh` in `.../MiKTeX/scripts/albatross` so I tried adding `.../MiKTeX/scripts` to my PATH but still it's not recognized.

Is MiKTeX missing an executable file in `MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64` or is something wrong with my setup?

I know albatross has some dependencies (Fontconfig, Java) but I'd like to first just get my machine to recognize the command.

As a sidenote, I also tried `albatross --version` on Ubuntu with the Debian texlive (contained in texlive-font-utils) and got a similar result: `albatross: command not found`.

Comment: This has been [reported](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/338) to miktex and will be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MiKTeX now provides an `albatross` executable which is available upon update.

Previously MiKTeX only included the necessary files which could be run manually using

```
java -jar albatross.jar
```

which, with Java SDK 20 installed and an appropriate path to the `albatross.jar`, would readily substitute for the executable.

Comment: Thanks. Does texlive create an executable? I'd like to know if this is a miktex packaging error as then I'll report it to miktex

Comment: In my TL 2023 (Linux) environment albatross works out of the box.

Comment: I don't know what TL does on Windows, but arara seems to be structured the same way (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/arara/scripts) and does work out of the box on MiKTeX.